# How to parse object to array in TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have to parse object like below:

```
const obj = {
    "package": {
        "dependencies": {
            "a": "b",
            "c": "d"
        }
    }
}
```

to this format:

```
const data = {
    "package": [
        {
            "dependencies": [
                { key: "a", value: "b" },
                { key: "c", value: "d" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone tell me how to do this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don't need to parse it. It's already a JavaScript object. What have you tried? Read about [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible. Without understanding the use case I feel that this sort of conversion might cause you more problems.
Anyhow the below is one way to achieve this.

```
const obj = {
    "package": {
        "dependencies": {
            "a": "b",
            "c": "d"
        }
    }
}

const packageArray = {
  package: [
    {
     dependencies: Object.entries(obj.package.dependencies)
      .map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work :

```js
const data = {...obj} // Copy the initial object
data.package.dependencies= Object.entries(obj.package.dependencies)
    .map(([key, value])=>({key,value}))
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, `Object.entries` + `Array.prototype.map` will give desired transformation:

```
const obj = {
    "package": {
        "dependencies": {
            "a": "b",
            "c": "d"
        }
    }
};
const data = {
    package: {
        dependencies: Object.entries(obj.package.dependencies).map(([key, value]) => ({key, value}))
    }
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, "  "));
```

Output:

```json
{
  "package": {
    "dependencies": [
      {
        "key": "a",
        "value": "b"
      },
      {
        "key": "c",
        "value": "d"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

TypeScript playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMBEADgIbADWRA5gKZ4BcG2uTeAJlQVWG2MAJZUQ6DJiNx4iQvPDwAaRqObBJLPPJEBfNZvUBuTKEiwWRKEVTDcxMpSr0sCmGw5dOfAfQDySKsCgA6TigAJ34IAAoERD8rcmo-J05uNwgASj8AWyICMLCAbVIqAE8ZGAA3IgAbAFcqAF0U1AA+GDD0AuKyypr1FJStTF19cAgQCqo-CpAKMIApAGUPADk-aBCwCl4AM0Kw41MSsCqKipK8HDxenSA)